# .Net file pattern picks up unwanted files (C#)

Tags: c#, .net, io

I have a command as below.  I find if I use a file pattern of `*.csv` it also picks up items with a `.csvx` extension.  Maybe it's a throwback to the 8.3 filename days - anyone know a way that would return them properly, preferably without rolling our own?

```
files = (from file in Directory.EnumerateFiles(sourceFolder, filePattern, SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly) select file).ToList();
```

Comment: Add the filePattern, just to be complete.

Comment: And there is no point in combining `ToList()` with `EnumerateFiles()`

Comment: @Henk  "I find if I use a file pattern of `*.csv` it also picks up items with a `.csvx`"

Comment: The 8.3 fallback sounds plausible, since the 8.3 name corresponding to a `*.csvx` file would indeed match the `*.csv` pattern.

Comment: @codeinc I'd rather see it with the `"` in a code block.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just a workaround but might be good enough:

```
var files = Directory
             .EnumerateFiles(sourceFolder, filePattern, SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly)
             .Where(f => f.EndsWith(".csv"))
             .ToList();
```

Comment: Thanks.  I had this workaround in mind, but it makes it more complex for the user to specify a pattern when the call the function (ie it's more hard coded).  Cheers!

Answer (score 3):

You can try something like this:

```
var files = (from file in Directory.EnumerateFiles(directory, "*.csv", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly)
                         select file).Where(c => c.EndsWith(".csv")).ToList();
```

Comment: Thanks xtian - it is as I feared!

Answer (score 1):

You could also use the "Extension" property

```
var files = new DirectoryInfo(path).GetFiles("*.csv").Where((info) => info.Extension = ".csv")
```

Comment: Yep, thanks for that.  Still doesn't properly implement the *.* pattern idea, but it's intended by the sound of it.  cheers

Answer (score 1):

This behaviour is by design:

> Because this method checks against file names with both the 8.3 file
>   name format and the long file name format, a search pattern similar to
>   "*1*.txt" may return unexpected file names. For example, using a
>   search pattern of "*1*.txt" returns "longfilename.txt" because the
>   equivalent 8.3 file name format is "LONGFI~1.TXT".

You will have to use one of the workarounds.

Source: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wz42302f.aspx